# set global variable's value in a function while check in another in python

Tags: python

My test script `test.py` is below:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

n = []
print('global', id(n))


def slowf():
    global n
    time.sleep(5)
    n.append(1)
    print('slowf---', n, id(n))


def checkn():
    global n
    while 1:
        if n:
            print('checkn', n, id(n), "T")
            break
        else:
            print('checkn', n, id(n), "F")
        time.sleep(1)


def main():
    global n
    p = Pool()
    p.apply_async(slowf, args=())
    p.apply_async(checkn, args=())
    p.close()
    p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And output of the script with running in `python3.6` is:

```
global 4534751304
checkn [] 4534751304 F
checkn [] 4534751304 F
checkn [] 4534751304 F
checkn [] 4534751304 F
checkn [] 4534751304 F
slowf--- [1] 4534751304
checkn [] 4534751304 F
checkn [] 4534751304 F
checkn [] 4534751304 F
checkn [] 4534751304 F
checkn [] 4534751304 F
......
```

So, why `slowf()` function has changed the global variable `n` after 5 seconds, but it still read a `[]` in `checkn()` function. They just both got into the global var `n` with the same `id`. I'm just confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate processes do not share memory. Changes you make in one child won't be visible in another.

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) explain this, and also why you often don't *want* shared state (you need to add synchronization, which is tricky to get right), and also what you can do instead.

[You *can* use explicit shared memory, but only with basic "C types" like 32-bit integers or arrays of floats](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects). And then you have to use explicit synchronization like `Lock` in the right places to make your code safe.

The ideal solution, when possible, is to redesign your code to [pass data over queues instead of sharing it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).

If that's not appropriate for your problem, you can use a [`Manager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers), which basically fakes shared high-level Python objects on top of a queue. This can be excruciatingly slow for some uses, but when it isn't, it can be the simplest answer.

Comment: Ok, I has read [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), and learned a lot from it. Finally, I choose to use a `Manager().Queue()`. It just works fine. Thank so much for your answer!